# Authenticate against Azure AD

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I'll try to make this as straight-forward as possible.
I have a ASP.NET Web API application running in Azure. I generate JWT tokens for callers, who authenticate with my service by sending in the equivalent of a username and password. Rather than managing my own membership database, I would like to utilize Azure Active Directory. I would then create users in AD.

My question is this: **From a web application running in Azure, can I make a simple API call to Azure Active Directory with a username and password and get back a result indicating that the user exists in AD?** If so, can you please point me in the right direction that will not eventually lead to a dead-end where I finally discover that it only will work for desktop applications, or some other contrived scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you are looking for an APi so that you can check whether user exist in AD or not. For checking if user exist in Azure AD or not , you can simply use Azure Graph rest api:

for which you can find the reference here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api?redirectedfrom=MSDN

you can simply utilise the below query with right set of filter:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version[&$filter]
```

Check this link for additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsers

https://forums.asp.net/t/2017251.aspx?Check+if+username+exist+in+Windows+Azure+Active+Directory+C+

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does this include validating the password?